# Populate Column with Diversity of Responses in Another Column Per Category

Tags: r

I am interested in the diversity of responses in Column B, within each category defined in Column A.

I can extract this data easily enough, I am however struggling to find a way to place it into a new column.

My data currently looks like: 

`A   B 
1   X
1   X
1   Z
1   Z
2   X
2   Y
2   Z
2   Z
2   Z
3   X
3   X
3   X
4   Y
4   Z`

The code I am currently using to define the diversity follows:

`df %>% count(A, B) %>% 
summarize(B.diversity = n())`

This returns information on the diversity that I want, noting the number of different responses within each category in Column A.

However I want to populate Column C with that information per category, as follows:
`A   B   C 
1   X   2
1   X   2
1   Z   2
1   Z   2
2   X   3
2   Y   3
2   Z   3
2   Z   3
2   Z   3
3   X   1
3   X   1
3   X   1
4   Y   2
4   Z   2`

Does anyone know of an efficient way to go about this?

Comment: How is 4, Z have 2? Does this work? `df %>% group_by(A, B) %>% 
    mutate(C = n())`

Comment: With base R, you can use `ave` like this: `ave(as.integer(df$B), df$A, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))`. In `data.table`, you'd do `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, C := uniqueN(B), by=A]`.

Comment: Since you already have the aggregated data, you could just merge them back. E.g. `df %>% right_join( df %>% count(A, B) %>% summarize(C = n()) )`. Note that this is basically your code wrapped into `right_join(df, ...)`.

Comment: @lmo The data.table function did exactly what I was hoping for -- thank you for the assist.